# <ui:composition template="/template.xhtml"> Invalid path : /template.xhtml

Tags: jsf-2, weblogic12c

Resource Library Contracts is not working on Weblogic 12.1.1. Wondering is it the version issue? Encounter the below error when try to access c1/index.xhtml

javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException: //seamnt/prd101/weblogic12_projects/testdomain/servers/testserver/stage/JavaWeb/JavaWeb/c1/index.xhtml @8,48  Invalid path : /template.xhtml

This is the war structure:

[image: War Structure]

WEB-INF/faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.1"
                          xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
                          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd">
        <application>
                <resource-library-contracts>
                        <contract-mapping>
                                <url-pattern>/c1/*</url-pattern>
                                <contracts>c1</contracts>
                        </contract-mapping>
                        <contract-mapping>
                                <url-pattern>/c2/*</url-pattern>
                                <contracts>c2</contracts>
                        </contract-mapping>
                </resource-library-contracts>
        </application>
</faces-config>
```

contracts/c1/template.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <h:outputStylesheet name="default.css"/>
        <title><ui:insert name="title">c1 Template</ui:insert></title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body styleClass="body">
        <h1><ui:insert name="h1">template.xhtml</ui:insert></h1>
        <h:graphicImage url="#{resource['duke.handsOnHips.gif']}"
                                alt="Duke with hands on hips"/>
        <ui:insert name="content"/>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

c1/index.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <ui:composition template="/template.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="title">c1 Index</ui:define>
        <ui:define name="h1">index.xhtml</ui:define>
        <ui:define name="content">
            <h:form>
                <div>Name: #{requestScopedBean.name}</div>
                <label>Name:
                    <h:inputText id="username"
                                 title="Name: "
                                 value="#{requestScopedBean.name}"
                                 required="true"
                                 requiredMessage="Error: A name is required."
                                 maxlength="25" />
                </label>
                <br/>
                <h:commandButton id="submit" value="Submit"
                                 action="index" />
                <h:commandButton id="reset" value="Reset" type="reset" />
            </h:form>
            <div class="messagecolor">
                <h:messages showSummary="true"
                            showDetail="false"
                            errorStyle="color: #d20005"
                            infoStyle="color: blue"/>
            </div>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resource library contracts was [introduced](http://jdevelopment.nl/jsf-22/#1142) in JSF 2.2.

You're using only JSF 2.1. This is not only indicated by the fact that you're using `version="2.1"` in `faces-config.xml`, but also the fact that WebLogic 12.1.x has JSF 2.1 built-in.

Logically, you've 2 options:

1. Upgrade to JSF 2.2 (this means, upgrade to WebLogic 12.2.x).
2. Drop the idea of using resource library contracts. It's a rather useless feature anyway.

Last but not least, make sure your versions match the learning resources and that you catch up the currently available versions. Make sure you learn JSF the right way. [Start here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info).

Comment: Regarding 2: Is it also 'rather useless' if you want to have one app with several different L&F options depending on which customer logs in?

Comment: @Kukeltje: With "useless" I didn't mean the purpose of the feature, but the implementation of the feature. You could with same amount of effort and code or even less achieve the same in a different/custom way.

Comment: Yes, that/a custom way we (I) now have. Were thinking about switching, but will postpone that...

Comment: @Kukeltje: Feel free to switch though. I personally only don't see how that's better/easier to maintain than just an EL expression in `library` attribute.

Comment: :-) waste of the effort for now. More important things to do